# Simulate Button Click With Event Change [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to simulate button click with event change. It works well but when i type a character in textbox, it calculates. I cant type the word. How can i fix this.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, autohesap);

function autohesap(event:Event) {
hesapla_btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextField` dispatches the `Event.CHANGE` every time it's contents are changed (e.g. a new character is entered). As you're adding the `Event.CHANGE` listener to the `stage`, the `stage` is going to pick up *all* the events of type `CHANGE`, including the one dispatched by your `TextField`. I'm not sure if this is the behaviour you're looking for?

If it is, and you "cant type the word", then it looks like it's because your `autohesap` is changing the `stage.focus` - when you click on a `TextField` to write in it, `stage.focus` is set to the `TextField` in question - if you manually set `stage.focus = null`, then the `TextField` will be deselected and you won't be able to type into any more, until you click it again.

Comment: Perfect. You found my mistake without looking my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a container object to hold all of the 'changeable' objects as children. But leave the textfield out of the container's 'family.' You can still position the textfield anywhere but its events will bypass the container, which will 'hear' events only in itself or its children.